# Using NumberFormatException in JTextField

Tags: java, try-catch, numberformatexception

So my program asks the user to input two integers then if the user inputs a string it will display an error message "Invalid! Please input an integer". But after the error message shows up it displays an error.

This is the error but I managed to convert the JTextField to String then to Integer

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at SimpleCalculator1.main(SimpleCalculator1.java:52)
```

And this is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class SimpleCalculator1 
{

        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
              int error1, error2;
              JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
              JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
              JTextField field3 = new JTextField();
              Object[] message = 
                   {
                       "Enter first integer:", field1,
                       "Input second integer:", field2,
                       "Choose the operation to be used\nAddition(+)\nSubtraction(-)\nMultiplication(*)\nDivision(/):", field3,
                   };
             int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "SimpleCalculator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
             boolean shouldExit = false;
             while(!shouldexit)
                  {
                       if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                         {
                                String value1 = field1.getText();
                                String value2 = field2.getText();         
                                String operation = field3.getText();

                                try
                                    {
                                         int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                         int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                    }
                                catch(NumberFormatException ne)
                                    {
                                         JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Invalid! Please input an integer","Error", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //When I press ok, I need help to bring me back to input entries
                                    }

                                switch(operation = field3.getText())
                                    {
                                       case "+":
                                       case "Addition":
                                             {
                                                  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                                  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                                  int result = num1+num2;
                                                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The sum is: "+result); 
                                                  break;
                                             }
                                       case "-":
                                       case "Subtraction":
                                             {
                                                  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                                  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                                  int result = num1-num2;
                                                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The difference is: "+result); 
                                                  break;
                                              }
                                        case "*":
                                        case "Multiplication":
                                              {
                                                  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                                  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                                  int result = num1*num2;
                                                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The product is: "+result); 
                                                  break;
                                              }
                                        case "/":
                                        case "Division":
                                              {
                                                  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                                  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                                  double result = (double)num1/num2;
                                                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The quotient is: "+result); 
                                                  break;
                                              }

                                       default: 
                                                  error1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Invalid operation, please try again","Error",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //I need help here for creating a loop that will take me back to the beginning.
                         }
                       option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "SimpleCalculator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

                  }
                       else if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION||)
                         {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you for using our program!");
                                shouldExit = true;
                         }


       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you catch `NumberFormatException` for field 1 and display an error, you continue on after the catch and attempt to parse a number from field3,which is not likely to be entered yet and then you again attempt to parse field 1 and 2 as numeric values. Extend your catch to wrap the process of all 3 fields and force the user to re-enter a valid value.

Moving your catch block to include parsing of all textfields and forcing the user to input a correct value can be done by modifying your while loop as shown here:

```
         boolean exit = false;
         while(!exit) {

            int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "SimpleCalculator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
            {
                String value1 = field1.getText();
                String value2 = field2.getText();         
                String operation = field3.getText();

                try{
                         int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                         int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);

                        operation = field3.getText();
                        if(operation != null){
                            operation = operation.toLowerCase();
                        }

                        switch(operation)  {
                               case "+":
                               case "addition":

                                          num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                          num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                          int result = num1+num2;
                                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The sum is: "+result); 
                                          break;

                               case "-":
                               case "subtraction":

                                          num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                          num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                          int result = num1-num2;
                                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The difference is: "+result); 
                                          break;

                                case "*":
                                case "multiplication":

                                          num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                          num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                          int result = num1*num2;
                                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The product is: "+result); 
                                          break;

                                case "/":
                                case "division":

                                          num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                          num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                          double result = (double)num1/num2;
                                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The quotient is: "+result); 
                                          break;

                               default: 
                                          error1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Invalid operation, please try again","Error",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //I need help here for creating a loop that will take me back to the beginning.
                        }
                        //option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "SimpleCalculator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException ne)
                {
                         JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Invalid! Please input an integer","Error", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //When I press ok, I need help to bring me back to input entries
                }

            }
            else if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you for using our program!");
                exit = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: The error was gone but when I don't input any operations or the operation is not the same in the choices the error "Invalid operation, please try again" won't display only the "Invalid! Please input an integer"

Comment: It is working for me. The key is that it first validates valid numbers and only if those are entered and valid will it validate the operation. So, if i enter valid numbers for the first and second integers, I see it give me a validation error correctly for the operation if it is not entered or an invalid one. Looks good to me.

Comment: I noticed that too.Thank you for your answer it helps me big time and I understood your solution. But there is one thing I need to ask an unrelated question to my problem, can I put equalsIgnoreCase() in a switch case statement?

Comment: No. You can pull out the line of code to set operation and place it above the switch statement. Then call operation.toLowerCase() to normalize it. But check for null before setting to lower case. Then you would change your case statement to all lower case like `case "addition":`

Comment: I have updated the answer to include your .toLowerCase implementation. Also, I commented out the extra line to showConfirmDialog that was forcing the user to click 'OK' twice before doing a calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I need to do is to study the logic of my code before the presentation.

Comment: I fixed that already, I had to remove the option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "SimpleCalculator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); outside the switch block

Answer (score 0):

RCA : First you check whether values entered in textfiles are integers in try catch.

```
try
                                {
                                     int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                     int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                }
                            catch(NumberFormatException ne)
                                {
                                     JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Invalid! Please input an integer","Error", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //When I press ok, I need help to bring me back to input entries
                                }
```

Whether they are  integers or not then you try to converte value in textfields to integers in switch statement. Then java try to converte those values to Interger  but he can't due to number format error. So that java disply that error.

Work arround : Move switch statement inside to try catch where check the textfields values.
Create int num1; int num2; as method local variable.

Final code :

```
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
          int error1, error2;
          JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
          JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
          JTextField field3 = new JTextField();
          int num1;
          int num2;
          Object[] message = 
               {
                   "Enter first integer:", field1,
                   "Input second integer:", field2,
                   "Choose the operation to be used\nAddition(+)\nSubtraction(-)\nMultiplication(*)\nDivision(/):", field3,
               };
         int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "SimpleCalculator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        boolean shouldexit = false;
         while(!shouldexit)
              {
                   if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION )
                     {
                            String value1 = field1.getText();
                            String value2 = field2.getText();         
                            String operation = field3.getText();

                            try
                                {
                                      num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                      num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);

                                               switch(operation = field3.getText())
                                {
                                   case "+":
                                   case "Addition":
                                         {
                                               num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                               num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                              int result = num1+num2;
                                              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The sum is: "+result); 
                                              break;
                                         }
                                   case "-":
                                   case "Subtraction":
                                         {
                                               num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                               num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                              int result = num1-num2;
                                              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The difference is: "+result); 
                                              break;
                                          }
                                    case "*":
                                    case "Multiplication":
                                          {
                                               num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                               num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                              int result = num1*num2;
                                              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The product is: "+result); 
                                              break;
                                          }
                                    case "/":
                                    case "Division":
                                          {
                                               num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                               num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                                              double result = (double)num1/num2;
                                              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The quotient is: "+result); 
                                              break;
                                          }

                                   default: 
                                              error1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Invalid operation, please try again","Error",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //I need help here for creating a loop that will take me back to the beginning.
                     }

                                }
                            catch(NumberFormatException ne)
                                {
                                     JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Invalid! Please input an integer","Error", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //When I press ok, I need help to bring me back to input entries
                                }


                   option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "SimpleCalculator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

              }
                   else 
                     {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you for using our program!");
                            shouldexit = true;
                     }


   }}
```

Comment: Thanks I did that already and It fix my problem. Thanks though.